# How to get average with orderBy Desc in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 tables in my database.

`books` and `ratings`

in `books`
`id`, `name`

in `ratings`

`id`, `book_id`, `rating`

i have set has many relationship for these models.

So in `Book` model -

```
public function ratings()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Rating');
}
```

in `Rating` Model -

```
public function book()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Book');
}
```

Now i want to fetch all books with there average rating but order by high rating.

so i high rated books first and then low ratings.

So How i can join 2 tables to achieve this result.

Thanks.

Comment: I would not leverage ORM on that. Doubt it will scale. Leverage the database. Get rankings and PKs, then after pagination use ORM and load those few by ID. In other words use SQL.

Comment: Thank you for reply. So how can i do this in SQL?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a modified `withCount()`:

```
$books = Book::withCount(['ratings as average_rating' => function($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('coalesce(avg(rating),0)'));
}])->orderByDesc('average_rating')->get();
```

Comment: how does it works if my column is float?? Now i ma getting unexpected result. 9.5 is getting first result and then 10.0 Is it happening because of float value?? here is `dd` -
http://prntscr.com/k4h4kv

Comment: i am getting first record with ratings 9.5 and second with 10.0 but i was expecting first record to be 10.0 and then 9.5

Comment: Please replace `->get()` with `->toSql()`: What's the result?

Comment: i found this article. i am using mysql 5.6. maybe this is a bug in my mysql?

Comment: You aren't using the code from my answer. There's no `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Now it is working. i had a small typo there. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

```
Books::withAvg('ratings', 'rating')->orderBy('ratings_avg_rating', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
```

this works in Laravel 8

Answer (score 0):

That query would look something like this:

```
SELECT book.id, AVG(ratings.rating) AS avg_rating 
FROM ratings
JOIN book ON book.id = ratings.book_id
/* WHERE AVG(ratings.rating) > 4 You could say only return results where rating > 4 */
GROUP BY book.id
ORDER BY AVG(ratings.rating) DESC LIMIT 5;
```

You need to join the two tables, use an aggregate function with a group by on the book. Then just sort and limit the results.

**UPDATE:**

In response to your question:

```
SELECT book.id, COALESCE(AVG(ratings.rating), 0) AS avg_rating 
FROM book
*LEFT* JOIN ratings ON book.id = ratings.book_id    
GROUP BY book.id
ORDER BY AVG(ratings.rating);
```

Use of a `view` might be something of a compromise between ease of the ORM and sanity in your querying.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. By doing this i will get only those books which has ratings. in my situation i need to get all the books. if a book does not have any rating then then it should give the result 0. 

so here now i ma getting data like this:
https://prnt.sc/k4gluv

But in my database i have more books but result i got only those books which has ratings. I need to fetch all the books.

Comment: OK. The `limit` then makes no sense right? To accomplish it though simply reverse the join direction. Strongly recommend learning SQL if you use a RDBMS. Just working with an ORM and not understanding what is going on under the hood is not ideal.

Comment: Yes. i do not need to `limit`. reverse the join means? Can you update your answer please?

Comment: it is giving me this result. http://prntscr.com/k4gvg9

in my database i have 12 books. But still it is getting only those books which has ratings

Comment: Force `LEFT JOIN`... See other answer (withCount) that looks to use the ORM but also a sane approach to retrieval and aggregation.

Comment: Thank you for giving your time. It helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

Via [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections)*

```
    $books = Book::with('ratings')
        ->get()
        ->sortBy(function($bk, $key) {
            if($bk->rating) {
                return $bk->rating->rating;
            }
            return null;
        });
```

Via Joins

```
  $books = Book::join('rating', 'rating.book_id', '=', 'book.id')
                 ->orderBy('ratings.rating', 'desc')
                 ->select('books.*')
                 ->get();
```

Comment: Your first method isn't using the ORM, it'd be using Laravel's collection methods since you're trying to perform an ordering operation after get(), however, I think you mean sortBy not orderBy.

Comment: @Devon, thank you I've corrected the answer and linked to the collections docs. Also yes, I did mean sortBy as well

Comment: And what if i want to calculate average rating and then get result according OrderBy DESC ??