# How to get all Users orderBy their ratings using Laravel 5 / Eloquent / query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i have these tables in my database.

`users`

`id      username`

then

`books`

`id        name       user_id`

`ratings`

`id        rating      book_id`

Now i want to fetch all the `users` and list them on the webpage but i need them to be order by ratings. So basically i need to check all users and their books then calculate the average rating of those books then get users according that average rating.

How can i do this using laravel or query builder?

i have relationship setup as following

`User` model

```
 public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Book');
    }
```

`Book` model

```
 public function ratings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Rating');
    }
```

`Rating` model

```
 public function book()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Book');
    }
```

P.S. if there is no rating for particular book then i want to return `0` ratings instead of `null` so in my webpage i could display that users rating as `0` 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use `hasManyThrough` in your `User` model, then you'll be able to use `withCount` to get the users you want in your controller.

```
class User extends Model
{
    function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Book');
    }

    function ratings()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Rating', 'App\Book');
    }
}
```

Once that is added, in your controller you just do similar to your last question but use User instead:
[How to get average with orderBy Desc in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252812/how-to-get-average-with-orderby-desc-in-laravel-5)

```
$users = User::withCount(['ratings as average_rating' => function($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('coalesce(avg(rating),0)'));
}])->orderByDesc('average_rating')->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: Thank you for reply :). i need to get average rating and not only count then need to order it.

Comment: so do i need `hasManyThrough` relationship here? and if i do then in model `ratings` method would not be taking first argument the final model which is `Rating` and not `Book` ?

Comment: That's correct. By using `hasManyThrough` you are accessing the distant relative and defining it in the model with your new `ratings()` function. You can then use it in an eloquent query like I shown you in my above answer.

Comment: Thanks! it solved my problem. please update your answer. i changed `ratings` method to  

 `public function ratings()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Rating', 'App\Book');
    }` 

By changing model order it works!
Thanks.

Comment: It may have also been my typo of `App\Ratings` which I just fixed now.