# How to order results by average rating

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Let's say that I have the following code which basically returns all movies with more than 5 total ratings:

```
$movies = Movie::where('private', 0)->with(['user', 'ratings', 'tagged'])->has('ratings', '>=', 5)->paginate(15)->onEachSide(1);
```

I would however also like to order those results by average rating for each movie. I am currently using [laravel-rateable](https://github.com/willvincent/laravel-rateable) to manage the ratings and it has a `->averageRating()` method which works fine but I have no idea how to take advantage of it and use it in the query above, if it's even possible. Maybe this can be achieved without using that specific method? Could someone point me in the right direction please?

**SOLUTION**: I ended up using the following answer which works just fine [How to get average with orderBy Desc in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252812/how-to-get-average-with-orderby-desc-in-laravel-5/51253593#51253593)

Comment: I looked into the package. Method `->averageRating()` just return `$this->ratings()->avg('rating')`.

Your question might be already answered in this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51253593/7329321

Comment: @Chhay Thanks, that seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about this one, but you can try:

```
$movies = Movie::where('private', 0)
    ->with(['user', 'ratings', 'tagged'])
    ->has('ratings', '>=', 5)
    ->orderBy(function($item) {return $item->averageRating();})
    ->paginate(15)->onEachSide(1);
```

Comment: Just tried that and got the following exception: `BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::averageRating()` `Bad Method Call Did you mean Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::average() ?`